# std::string comparison, lexicographical or not

Tags: c++, string

The following code, comes from the article [C++ quirks, part 198276](https://sigsegv.me/2013/12/02/c-quirks-part-198276/)

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::string a = "\x7f";
    std::string b = "\x80";
    cout << (a < b) << endl;
    cout << (a[0] < b[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly the [output](http://ideone.com/CSvV0u) is

```
1
0
```

Shouldn't string comparison be lexicographical ? If yes how is the output explained?

Comment: Did you read the explanation that was given on the website? What about that explanation did not make sense to you?

Comment: @sharth It seems to be violating what [lexicographical comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is; both as a mathematical and as a programming concept. The question is  about that, _Shouldn't string comparison be lexicographical ?_ Why the need to override a well established definition? Should we be worried whenever `lexicographical` pops up in the Standard, am I (sort of) worried over a single exception. I mean it's taxonomy of concerns emmited when making a detour around a solid concept.

Comment: Note that [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is not [Alphabetical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order). We are sorting the strings lexicographically. To sort them alphabetically, you need information about the character encoding. A `std::string` does not store any information about this, which means it doesn't know if a particular character in the string is a `A` or `©`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the C++ specification to say if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, it's up to the compiler. For your compiler it seems that `char` defaults to `signed char` which is why the second comparison returns `false`.

Comment: I tried for numbers less than 7F and got both results same. Your explanation seems perfect.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm just going to quote directly from [your link](https://sigsegv.me/2013/12/02/c-quirks-part-198276/):

> It turns out that this behavior is required by the standard, in section 21.2.3.1 [char.traits.specializations.char]: “The two-argument members eq and lt shall be defined identically to the built-in operators == and < for type unsigned char .”

So:

- `(a < b)` is required to use `unsigned char` comparisons.
- `(a[0] < b[0])` is required to use `char` comparisons, which may or may not be signed.